# Can I travel to the UK if my Schengen visa expired?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, europe

I am Vietnamese. I have a resident permit (ID) in Belgium. It will expire on 31.09.2014, but I have the UK visa valid until December.
Can I still go to the UK from Belgium with the nearly-expired ID?
I ask because I heard someone told me that I cannot go to the UK if my resident permit expires soon.

Comment: Well, you probably can't enter the UK for longer than your resident permit. What is your nationality (I assume you have a passport since you mention visa). Your resident permit won't affect your visa to the UK, only your passport's validity will.

Comment: What kind of UK visa do you have?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have general visitor visa. I just want to stay few weeks then I will come back to Vietnam, not Belgium anymore.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have a UK visa I don't see why your expiring residence permit should matter. Make sure you enter the UK with the UK visa and not with the residence card.

Comment: While probably a valid answer, it'd be far more useful with a link or reference.  Now he's just in the position where someone told him he can't go, and you've told him he can go. Who does he believe?

Comment: he can go because the visa is valid, the problem is to back to Belgium with an expired residence permit.

Comment: @GuidoPreite Excellent point, but it seems the OP clarified that they would go back to Vietnam instead.